# Use Mathematica to implement a Penney's game solver

Tags: graphics, markov-process

In [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game) , player A selects a sequence of heads and tails (of length 3 or larger), and shows this sequence to player B. Player B then selects another sequence of heads and tails of the same length. Subsequently, a fair coin is tossed until either player A's or player B's sequence appears as a consecutive subsequence of the coin toss outcomes. The player whose sequence appears first wins.

---

Here is a simple Monte Carlo:

```
(*Clear all previous definitions and variables*)
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Define the patterns*)
pattern1 = {0, 1, 1};  (*THH*)
pattern2 = {0, 0, 1};  (*TTH*)

(*Initialize win counters for each pattern*)
win1 = 0;
win2 = 0;

(*Set the sequence length and number of implementations*)
seqLength = 100;
implementations = 1000000;

(*Run the main simulation loop*)
Do[(*Generate a random binary sequence of length seqLength*)
 seq = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, seqLength];
 (*Check each position in the sequence for a pattern match*)
 For[i = 1, i <= seqLength - 2, i++, 
  If[Take[seq, {i, i + 2}] == pattern1, win1 += 1;
   Break[];];
  If[Take[seq, {i, i + 2}] == pattern2, win2 += 1;
   Break[];];], {impl, 1, implementations}]

(*Output the win counters*)
{win1, win2}
```

$$
\{332964,667036\}
$$

So we say, when 2 players seperately select "THH" and "TTH" patterns, the winning propability of the player who select "THH" is roughly $\frac{1}{3}$, and the winning propability of the player who select "TTH" is roughly $\frac{2}{3}$.

---

We can use *Markov Process* to understand how the game works. I implemented a Penney's game solver below.

Answer (score 4):

1. Calculate the *adjacency list* `transitionDict`.
2. Then convert the *adjacency list* `transitionDict` into the *adjacency matrix* `transitionMatrix`.
3. A *discrete Markov process* `markovProcess` is established based on the *adjacency matrix* `transitionMatrix`.
4. Finally, calculate the *stationary distribution* of the created `markovProcess`.

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];

pattern1 = "THH";
pattern2 = "TTH";

(*Some assertions*)
On[Assert];
Assert[StringMatchQ[pattern1, 
   Repeated["H" | "T", {StringLength[pattern1]}]]];
Assert[StringMatchQ[pattern2, 
   Repeated["H" | "T", {StringLength[pattern2]}]]];
Assert[StringLength[pattern1] == StringLength[pattern2]];

(*Find all distinct prefixes*)
prefixes = 
  Union[StringTake[pattern1, #] & /@ Range[StringLength[pattern1]], 
   StringTake[pattern2, #] & /@ Range[StringLength[pattern2]]];

(*Add empty string as a state*)
prefixes = Append[prefixes, ""];

(*Sort prefixes by length in descending order*)
orderedPrefixes = ReverseSortBy[prefixes, StringLength];

(*Define transition probabilities*)
transitions[prefix_] := 
  Module[{newH, newT, suffixH, suffixT}, newH = prefix <> "H";
   newT = prefix <> "T";
   suffixH = FirstCase[orderedPrefixes, _?(StringEndsQ[newH, #] &)];
   suffixT = FirstCase[orderedPrefixes, _?(StringEndsQ[newT, #] &)];
   {suffixH -> 1/2, suffixT -> 1/2}];
selftoselfTransitions[prefix_] := {prefix -> 1};

(*Create Markov process*)
transitionDict = 
  AssociationMap[transitions, Drop[orderedPrefixes, 2]]~Join~
   AssociationMap[selftoselfTransitions, Take[orderedPrefixes, 2]];

(*Get all unique states*)
states = Union[Keys[transitionDict], 
   Flatten[Keys /@ Values[transitionDict]]];

(*Map states to integers*)
stateToIndex = AssociationThread[states -> Range[Length[states]]];

(*Initialize transition matrix*)
transitionMatrix = ConstantArray[0, {Length[states], Length[states]}];

(*Fill in the transition matrix*)
Do[Do[{transitionMatrix[[stateToIndex[state], 
        stateToIndex[nextState]]] = (Association @@ 
         transitionDict[state])[nextState];}, {nextState, 
    Keys[transitionDict[state]]}], {state, Keys[transitionDict]}];

(*Create the Markov process*)
markovProcess = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, transitionMatrix];


(*List common Markov process properties*)
MarkovProcessProperties[markovProcess]


(*Find final stationary distribution*)
StationaryDistribution@markovProcess
stateToIndex
```

$$
\text{ProbabilityDistribution}\left[\frac{1}{3} \text{Boole}[\underline{x}=4]+\frac{2}{3} \text{Boole}[\underline{x}=6],\{\underline{x},1,6,1\}\right]
\\
\text{Association}[\varnothing\to 1,\text{T}\to 2,\text{TH}\to 3,\text{THH}\to 4,\text{TT}\to 5,\text{TTH}\to 6]
$$

The result is consistent with [*the graph of best responses*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Penney_game_graphs.svg).

---

Visualize it based on the *adjacency list* `transitionDict`

```mathematica
(*First we import the required packages*)
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

(*Convert the dictionary to a list of directed edges*)
edgeList = 
  Flatten[KeyValueMap[
    Function[{key, val}, key \[DirectedEdge] # & /@ Keys[val]], 
    transitionDict]];

(*Generate a list of edge labels as the probabilities*)
edgeLabels = 
  Flatten[KeyValueMap[
    Function[{key, val}, 
     Thread[(key \[DirectedEdge] # & /@ Keys[val]) -> Values[val]]], 
    transitionDict]];

(*Generate the graph*)
g = Graph[edgeList, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> edgeLabels, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexSize -> 0.4]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice: thank you for sharing.  I played with it (with attribution):[here](https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2023/12/09/penney-full-of-thoughts/).